# Add validation of 30 alphabets allowed to new shipping address form field. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, validation

How do i add validation of maximum 30 alphabets allowed to shipping address form field
in checkout page magento 2 ?
https://prnt.sc/rz0n58

Answer (score 1):

To change the validation of the for shipping address you need to create after plugin for jsLayout.

check below example to resolve your issue.

Step 1. Create Magento 2 module

Step 2. declare plugin in vendorname/modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml file

> vendorname/modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <plugin name="checkout_modification" type="vendorname\modulename\Plugin\AfterJsConfig"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create Plugin file to modify JsLayout and return it back to checkout page.

> vendorname/modulename/Plugin/AfterJsConfig.php

```
<?php
namespace vendorname\modulename\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class AfterJsConfig
{
    /**
     * @var Json
     */
    protected $serializer;

    /**
     * AfterJsConfig constructor.
     * @param Json $serializer
     */
    public function __construct(
        Json $serializer
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    /**
     * @param Onepage $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetJsLayout(Onepage $subject, $result) {
        try {
            if ($result != "") {
                $jsonLayoutArray = $this->serializer->unserialize($result);

                // you can add more modification here.

                $jsonLayoutArray['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
                ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
                ['children']['street']['children'][0]['config']['validation']['max_text_length'] = 30;

                return $this->serializer->serialize($jsonLayoutArray);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Hope this solution help you to complete you task.

Note: Please make it right and add plus to this solution if this solution work for you.

Thank you

Comment: I have added plugin because street address fields are not override by using xml.

Comment: Will it work for "Address line 1 & 2 field" in shipping address ?

Comment: Though i've added the validation with different code.

Comment: you can add it for address line one as well as two also.
only you need to modify the array and add changes as per your requirements.

also you can add your additional validation also.

Comment: Sounds great ! So this code " $jsonLayoutArray['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
                ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
                ['children']['street']['children'][0]['config']['validation']['max_text_length'] = 30;" selects the shipping address fields and validate ?

Comment: yes you can check array elements there is [0] mentioned means address line-1 as well as you can change or add for [1] and [2].

also you can add and edit validation as shown in example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106733/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-nirav-patel).

Comment: can you please advise what modifications needs to be done to change the lable in that plugin ?

Comment: You can log whole js layout and check. Then you will get idea to modify any details of that.

Comment: To modify label for shipping address you can use below code.  $jsonLayoutArray['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
                ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
                ['children']['street']['label'] = ""label";

Comment: can i embed this code in the above one ?

Comment: Is their any variable something gets set if we select new billing address in checkout ? Actually the issue is whenever i change shipping address , billing address sets itself as shipping address.

Comment: Please add separate question for that so anyone can help you.

Comment: can you please take a look at - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310808/billing-address-issue-onchange-shipping-address-magento-2

Comment: Billing-address.js have some error , i've also posted the code

Comment: This does'nt seems to be working.