# How to change "Street Address: Line 1" label in one step checkout magento 2 shipping address?

Tags: magento2, shipping, onestepcheckout

change "Street Address: Line 1" label in one step checkout magento 2 ?

Comment: Any better answer ?

Answer (score 2):

hello you can modify any detail by using below solution please look into it.

In that solution I answered to modify validation for street address line 1 by using plugin.

you can also modify any other details as you like.

[Add validation of 30 alphabets allowed to new shipping address form field. Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310366/add-validation-of-30-alphabets-allowed-to-new-shipping-address-form-field-magen#answer-310419)

Thank You