# Magento 2 Set Default Zip/Postal Code in cart page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, knockoutjs

I have overridden the vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/LayoutProcessor.php in my module and added below code to set the default value of postcode

```
 class LayoutProcessorPlugin
 {
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, array $jsLayout)
    {
       $jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets']['children']['postcode']['value'] = '90091';
      return $jsLayout;
    }
 }
```

But somehow when visiting the cart page it is not filling the default value in the 'Zip/Postal' field. Can someone tell me how to achieve this? I guess some knockout js code overrides this value. I don't know where I need to set this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below answer it will help you to modify JSLAYOUT of checkout page.

then you can manage your changes and achieve the same that as you want.

[Add validation of 30 alphabets allowed to new shipping address form field. Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310366/add-validation-of-30-alphabets-allowed-to-new-shipping-address-form-field-magen/310419#310419)

Hope this will work for you.

Thank you,
Nirav Patel

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after debugging I found the solution

The default postcode can be set by overriding the TaxConfigProvider class. To set it you have to use after plugin.

Step 1: Define plugin in di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\TaxConfigProvider">
            <plugin disabled="false" name="My_Module_Plugin_Frontend_Magento_Tax_Model_TaxConfigProvider" sortOrder="10" type="My\Module\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Tax\Model\TaxConfigProvider"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

Step 2: Create a plugin class

```
<?php


namespace My\Module\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Tax\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

class TaxConfigProvider
{

    /**
     * @var CookieManagerInterface
     */
    private $cookieManager;

    /**
     * TaxConfigProvider constructor.
     * @param CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
    ) {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxConfigProvider $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxConfigProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $result['defaultPostcode'] = $this->cookieManager->getCookie('custom_pincode');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

After implementing this code go to Store –> Configuration –> General –> Country Options here you will find an option of “Zip/Postal Code is Optional for”. Remove the country for which you want to set default zip code from this list otherwise, it will be not filled up in frontend.